# How should I implement different dotfiles per system?

Tags: configuration, git, configuration-management

At the moment, I'm using `yadm` with a git repository to synchronize my dotfiles across different laptops. A problem has occurred though: for some applications, one laptop needs a slightly different dotfile than the other. In some dotfiles (`~/.zshrc` for example), I was able to fix this by checking for the hostname:

```
HOSTNAME=`hostname`
if [ "$HOSTNAME" = "asus" ]; then
    alias sp="cd ~/data/spreadsheets"
else
    alias sp="cd ~/spreadsheets"
fi
```

This does not work for every dotfile though. A lot of dotfiles don't allow scripting. How can I have a different hostfile for each system yet keep all of them in one git repository? Perhaps this can be done by symlinking some files right after booting, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Looking at the yadm site, it has this built-in: [Alternate Files](https://thelocehiliosan.github.io/yadm/docs/alternates)

Comment: @wjandrea, thanks for this suggestion, perhaps you can change it into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I've never used yadm, so I wouldn't know how to explain it. You're welcome to post your own answer! :)